# AngularJS: calling controller function inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angularjs-ng-repeat

My **controller** looks something like this:

```
controller('MonthlyCalendarController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.counter = 0;

    $scope.increment = function() {
        $scope.counter++;
        console.log($scope.counter);
    }
 }])
```

My **HTML** looks something like this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="x in y track by $index" ng-init="increment()">
counter: {{counter}}
 </div>
```

My **output** looks like this every time. It only ever shows "1":

```
 <div>counter: 1</div>
```

It console.logs() correctly; logging incremental numbers. However, my HTML output is only "1" every time. Just outputting $index will not suffice, as I'm doing other math in my `increment()` function, and `$scope.counter` will `!= $index`. Any ideas?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve that lead you to try this approach?

Comment: I'm building a calendar, but the ng-repeat really has nothing to do with the function to be called. I just need the function called every time the repeat happens. That's why I just used 'x in y' in my ng-repeat; just to illustrate the concept. But to elaborate a bit, this is the 'day' in the calendar, and depending on the value of calendar, different things will show in that 'day'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lqzN3P2aXT9yA8DGwG5O?p=preview)

"*Just outputting $index will not suffice, as I'm doing other math in my increment() function, and $scope.counter will != $index. Any ideas?*"

You can still use `$index` this way:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in y track by $index">
  counter: {{increment($index)}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.increment=function(counter){
    $scope.counter=++counter;
    // do your stuff with $scope.counter
    return $scope.counter;
}
```

> **$index** returns iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)

Comment: Calling the function in brackets instead of ng-init() seems to have solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use directive:

Live example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/gwzkw1bb/1/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MonthlyCalendarController', MonthlyCalendarController);

function MonthlyCalendarController($scope) {
  $scope.y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  $scope.counter = 0;
  $scope.increment = function() {
        $scope.counter++;
        console.log($scope.counter);
    }
}

myApp.directive('increment',function(){
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    transclude:true,
    scope:{
      increment:"=",
      innerIncrement:"=",
    },
    template: '<span ng-transclude></span>',
    link:function(scope,elem,attr){
     scope.$parent.increment = scope.increment;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MonthlyCalendarController">
    <div ng-repeat="x in y track by $index" ng-init="increment()" increment="counter">
    counter {{increment}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `counter` value is `2-way` binded hence it will print last value all the time.

Use `$index` which will give offset of the iterator.

Try this:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MonthlyCalendarController', MonthlyCalendarController);

function MonthlyCalendarController($scope) {
  $scope.y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  $scope.counter = 0;

  $scope.increment = function() {
    $scope.counter++;
    console.log($scope.counter);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MonthlyCalendarController">
    <div ng-repeat="x in y track by $index" ng-init="increment()">
      counter: {{$index+1}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/Lt7aP/2111/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `ng-init` function to set a value on each item:

To demonstrate that we can calculate each item independentally of the index, here's an example which assigns each item the next fibonacci number.

Your template:

```
  <div ng-repeat="x in y track by $index" ng-init="increment(x)">
      <strong>{{x.counter }}</strong>: {{ x.name}} 
  </div>
```

And the code:

```
app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('MonthlyCalendarController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.y = [{
    name: "One"
  }, {
    name: "Two"
  }, {
    name: "Three"
  }, {
    name: "Four"
  }, {
    name: "Five"
  }];

  var counter = 0;

  var getNextFibonacciNumber = (function() {
    var seq = [0, 1];
    return function() {
      seq = [seq[1], seq[0] + seq[1]];
      return seq[1];
    };
  })();

  $scope.increment = function(item) {
    item.counter = getNextFibonacciNumber();
  }
}]);
```

Results in:

```
1: One
2: Two
3: Three
5: Four
8: Five
```

The [plunker is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CyRC3PBSZuwRcURHJoCa?p=preview).